# Possible to save screen resolution settings and quickly switch between them?

Tags: resolution

I have different screen resolutions I need for various situations, for example:

- Mac Retina while mobile: 1680x1050
- Mac Retina + Thunderbolt: default (equal scaling on both monitors)
- (optional) Mac Retina 1680x1050 + Thunderbolt: default (equal scaling on both monitors)

Comment: I'd suggest [cscreen](http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/), but there's no confirmation it works well/at all on Retina MBPs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, but it's possible to check the "Show displays in menu bar" option in System Preferences -> Displays. This adds a menubar item which allows you to quickly switch between recently used resolutions

[image]

Alternatively, maybe something like [Display Maestro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-maestro/id414546485?mt=12) or [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/functions/menus/menus.html) would help? These both seem to have the ability to display and switch between recently used resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [QuickRes](http://menulet.wewewe.me/?mId=55). You can try it.

> **QuickRes** is the quickest and easiest way to switch between screen resolutions on the MacBook Pro with Retina Display. With just a single click or simple key-combo you can give your Mac more screen space than ever before with sizes ranging up to 3840x2400!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, just plugging in a monitor I've previously used will revert to the Display settings I last used with that monitor. So rather than needing to switch between recent display settings, I just need to plug it in and it switches automatically.

When I plug my computer into the DVI projector at work, it switches to 720p as the last-used setting with that projector, but when I use the external monitor on my desk, it uses the native 1680x1050 resolution.

I don't know if this works with VGA monitors, since I don't think the computer can actually identify the monitor(?), but would assume this generally applies to digital connections (DVI, HDMI, Thunderbolt).